# Access Local json from any folder or class

Tags: javascript, react-native

i have a locally saved json file and my app have lots on folders and classes. i am saving my json in one folder and i want to know if there is any way i can access that local json from classes saved in 'A' folder and than same way to access from a class saved in 'B' folder without changing path everytime for every class in require(). i simple word is there a way to create a universal path for my json file that can be accessed from any class from any folder.

currently

```
require('./src/components/atomic/en.json') for class 'A'
require('..//components/atomic/en.json') for class 'B'
```

i need one universal path for every class.